# Is it possible to remove the filter from 4.8 text widget?

Tags: filters, widgets

The new rich text widget that came with the 4.8 update seems to add a filter to widget's content before outputting the data (probably `the_content`).

I just noticed that if i use a shortcode in the new text widget, it will mess the entire thing ( for example, it will replace the `X` letter with `&#215;` which is the HTML entity equivalent for `×` mark, add random `<p>`, etc.). The filter is added to the `wp_options` table under `widget_text`, like this:

```
a:2:{
    i:2;
    a:3:{
        s:5:"title";
        s:6:"Sample";
        s:4:"text";
        s:14:"[shortcode-here]";
        s:6:"filter";
        s:7:"content";
    }
    s:12:"_multiwidget";
    i:1;
}
```

Now if i replace the 5th and 6th values with this:

```
    s:1:" ";
    s:1:" ";
```

The filter is applied no more. If you already have a text widget added before updating to 4.8, there won't be a problem. But the moment you click `Save` on the widget after you update to 4.8, the problem appears.

I don't want to disable the filter entirely, since there might be other text widgets on the page.

Is it possible to detect the shortcodes and turn off the filter for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now have a new filter `widget_text_content` introduced in 4.8 <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/39d2d9f19e705aa58fb140b354bc58e7d7ff454f/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-text.php#L84-L103)</sup>, with the following default callbacks:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text_content', 'capital_P_dangit', 11 );
add_filter( 'widget_text_content', 'wptexturize'          );
add_filter( 'widget_text_content', 'convert_smilies',  20 );
add_filter( 'widget_text_content', 'wpautop'              );
```

that are applied if the *filter* settings, for the widget instance, is set to `'content'`.

When you remove the filter settings by hand from the `wp_options` table, it seems to be reset during the update method <sup>[src](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/39d2d9f19e705aa58fb140b354bc58e7d7ff454f/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-text.php#L142)</sup>.

See trac ticket [#35243](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35243) for more info.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. So, is there a chance to turn off these filters just for my shortcodes? Or do i have to turn them off for everything? That won't be nice...

Comment: Yes that would be possible, with a hack, using e.g. the `widget_display_callback` to check if the text widget contains any shortcode and remove those above filters, else leave them on for others. But this widget seems to be a work in process these days, so we should stay tuned ;-)

Comment: As always, nice to read your detailed answer. My theme just got rejected again because it doesn't display shortcodes properly inside the widget, so i guess i have to create a widget for each of them :( Automattic please!

Comment: Sorry to hear that, it's a long process, that will hopefully be rewarding for you in the end. Custom widgets are probably a good workaround.